# How can I access kubernetes service via dns name from localhost on which is Docker Desktop/Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-statefulset

I have such configuration `localhost` on which is installed Docker Desktop with Kubernetes.

I deployed for example some cassandra server as statefulset I created such service to expose individual pods from statefulset. I can not use `cassandra` service since for some Cassandra operation default load balancing is toxic. I need to connect all pods in headless service or selected seed pods - proxyless option is the best choice in this case by design.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cassandra-0
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: cassandra-0
  ports:
  - name: cql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9042
    targetPort: 9042
```

I want to expose it as cassandra-0.*.* inside localhost.

What should I do to make it in the easiest way?

What I imagine now but maybe it not need.

1. Configure some localhost dns to point cassandra-0:9042 to port 9042.
2. Use nginx to route traffic to specific exposed ports (9042,9043, ...) for (cassandra-0, cassandra-1, ...)

I plan to make test from localhost using pods in kubernetes.

Comment: I work around a similar need for Kafka by adding an entry to `/etc/hosts` on my developer workstation.  I usually recommend against `/etc/hosts` (because it's very manual and can lead to contextual problems) but it can be necessary (a) specifically on a developer workstation where you don't need to reproduce the setup, and (b) when talking to a clustered database that advertises the host names of the cluster members.

Comment: Problem is if you have 4 nodes you can not use 4 ports in Cassandra connection only one port and 4 names.